# I get the error "TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")" with function dirToArray

Tags: php

I am reading directories with images for a website with the function `dirToArray`.

I get for every directory **one entry too much**. This is named `Array`, and the error appears. It appears for every directory. How can I get rid of this entry?

the function:

```
<?php 
function dirToArray($dir) {  
    $result = array(); 
    $cdir = scandir($dir); 
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value){ 
        if (!in_array($value,array(".","..","Array"))){ 
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)){ 
                $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
            }else{ 
                $result[] = $value; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    return $result; 
} 
?>
```

My Code to read the directories:

```
<?php
$result=dirToArray("source");

foreach ($result AS $key => $value) {
    $head = preg_replace('#_#',' ', $key);
    echo '<h2>'.$head.'</h2>';

    foreach ($value AS $subKey => $subValue) {
      $titel = preg_replace('#_#',' ', subValue);
      echo '<img src="backend/source/'.$key.'/'.$subValue.'" alt="'.$titel.'" />';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop to print `$result` assumes it's a 2-dimensional array: everything in the top-level of the array is directories, and the 2nd level is all files. If you have more levels in your directory hierarchy, this will not be correct. `dirToArray()` returns a nested hierarchy of arrays that mirrors the directory structure.

Therefore, you need a recursive function to print it, just like the recursive function you used to create it.

```
function printDirArray($dirname, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $head = str_replace('_', ' ', $key); // don't need `preg_replace` for ordinary characters
            echo "<h2>$head</h2>";
            printDirArray("$dirname/$head", $value);
        } else {
            $titel = str_replace('_', ' ', $value);
            echo '<img src="backend/source/'.$dirname.'/'.$value.'" alt="'.$titel.'" />';
        }
    }
}

$result = dirToArray("source");
printDirArray("source", $result);
```

Comment: Now I have a problem with the path for the images. 
The `else`-Part of the function returns for the `$key` a number. I need here the direction, that was read out in the first part of the function.
This I get:
`<img src="source/0/picture.jpg" />`
But I want:
`<img src="source/dir/picture.jpg" />`

The function reads now more levels, but its enough for me, when it reads only two.

Comment: The problem is that you're mixing associative and indexed elements in the array. You're using a named key for subdirectories, and numeric keys for ordinary files.

Comment: I think I've fixed it. You need to pass the parent directory name to the recursive function, so that when you're printing a file you can put the directory there.